# The easiest way to bevel the border

Tags: html, css

What I have:

[image: First]

What I need:

[image: Second]

*Code: http://codepen.io/marekkobida/pen/aNpKaV?editors=1100*

HTML

```
<div class="experiment">
  <h1>Experiment</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body { margin: 2rem; }

.experiment {
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;

  &::before {

  }

  &::after {

  }
}
```

Comment: it might be best to use a couple transforms instead.

Comment: @DanielA.White - Can you explain how?

Comment: Transform rectangle $\alpha$ degrees then transform text$-\alpha$ degrees.

Comment: @ArifBurhan - Which transform command should I use? skewY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skew is the best way for this to work.

```
.experiment {
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  transform: skew(0deg, -10deg);
}
```

Comment: I've never seen **padding: 2rem;**  before

Answer (score 0):

add

transform:skew(0deg, -10deg);
margin-top:8rem;

it will come exact output